# how to view source of native methods in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-ndk

I am in Android Studio diving into the source code of Android. As I dig deeper, I get to a method of the form, say, `native_setup(name, nameIsType, encoder);`. When I click through, all I get is

```
private native final void native_setup(
        @NonNull String name, boolean nameIsType, boolean encoder);
```

I want to see the source of that `native` method right from inside Android Studio. How might I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to attach GDB to your app Bedug thread and set your native source path. You can find more info here :

- https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-studio-debug/
- https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/astudio/
- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-debugging-with-remote-GDB